# Why am I getting incorrect output for input -100000000000000?

Tags: java, types, long-integer

```
    public class dataType {

    public static  void  main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                long x=sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
                if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte");
                if(x>=-1*(int)(Math.pow(2,15)) && x<=(int)(Math.pow(2,15)-1))System.out.println("* short");
                if(x>=-1*(int)(Math.pow(2,31)) && x<=(int)(Math.pow(2,31)-1))System.out.println("* int");
                if((x>=-1*(int)(Math.pow(2,63))) &&( x<=(int)(Math.pow(2,63)-1)))
                    System.out.println("* long");


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
                sc.next();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> For the Input number= -100000000000000,
>       Expected Output = -100000000000000 can be fitted in:
>                          * long 
>       Actual Output   =  -100000000000000 can be fitted in:
>
> Problem is that it is not printing the message after the last if
>   condition    to check whether the number is in range of long data
>   type.

Comment: Instead of all these computations, it would be better to use MINVALUE and MAXVALUE available with each wrapper class for the primitive data types. Most of the assertion errors that you get should go away.

Comment: Example, replace if(x>=-128 && x<=127)System.out.println("* byte"); with if(x>= Byte.MINVALUE && x<=Byte.MAXVALUE)System.out.println("* byte");

Comment: @Kavitha , I am facing issue with the condition that's checking whether the number is in range of Long data type and prints Long...after checking the if condition it's not printing the *long

Comment: Did you try changing that condition from if((x>=-1*(int)(Math.pow(2,63))) &&( x<=(int)(Math.pow(2,63)-1))) to if(X>=Long.MINVALUE && X<= Long.MAXVALUE) ? What is the output that you get after that change?

Comment: `(int)(Math.pow(2,63)` is sure to overflow -- that value doesn't fit in an `int` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can get tedious. Use the Wrapper class methods so you could work without providing then ranges themselves.

For instance:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int t = sc.nextInt();
      int x = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i <=t;i++) {
          x = sc.nextInt();
          try  {
            if(x >= BYTE.MINVALUE && x <= BYTE.MAXVALUE) System.out.println("Byte");
           //Same format for all required datatypes

          }
          catch(Exception e)  {
              System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
              sc.next();
          }
       }

      }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for loop is for the number of test cases that has nothing to do with condition check. So it won't make any difference to the code , whether the loop is there or not.

Comment: @PrernaBhadoria, yes that's correct. Let me modify my answer accordingly. Please approve it if it works!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the line where you have `(int)(Math.pow(2,63)` results in overflow? You'd have to store that in a larger datatype such as a `long`

Answer (score 0):

sir actually there was no need for (int)Math.pow(2,63) because it would cause a overflow